# Is it possible to pause phablet-dev-bootstrap command?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, porting-ubuntu-touch

I would want to know if it is possible to pause the

```
phablet-dev-bootstrap
```

For e.g. if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will I be able to resume the command if I re run the command `phablet-dev-bootstrap`.

If yes, then how?

Edit: I had paused the `phablet-dev-bootstrap` process by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, when I had to resume I retyped the command, but I got around 5 GB of sources, which should instead be 15GB.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is press Ctrl+C and stop the syncing.
When you are ready next time, just execute

> phablet-dev-bootstrap phablet -c

It should continue the repo sync from where it is stoped